# Does Ray Palmer from Arrow become Atom?

Tags: dc, arrow, arrowverse

I remember from a few episodes ago that Palmer is semi-attached to Atom.

Are there plans to branch another superhero from Arrow like they did for Flash?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Yes, it appears the former **[Man of Steel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348150/)**, Brandon Routh will be taking up the costume of the Atom, working at least for a time, with Oliver Queen and Team Arrow.

**From [TVLine](http://tvline.com/2014/07/07/arrow-brandon-routh-the-atom-season-3/):**

> - Brandon Routh is set to play another DC Comics super man — this time on Arrow.
>     The erstwhile Man of Steel is joining the CW hit’s third season in the recurring role of Ray Palmer, aka DC superhero The Atom, TVLine has learned exclusively.
> - In addition to his myriad comic book appearances, Ray/The Atom — who can alter the size of his body as well as objects — has turned up in numerous animated series, including, most recently, Cartoon Network’s Young Justice. Arrow marks one of the character’s rare live-action incarnations.

Comment: Oversaturisation... But then again we have the same deal with other kinds of shows. Too many hospital shows/cop shows7 variations of the above that have some kind of a twist.

Comment: @Cherubel - not sure you can have oversaturation when it comes to good superhero shows. Still, I can't see The Atom carrying his own show, so I'm assuming he'll just be a supporting character on Arrow and/or The Flash.

Comment: @Thaddeus - may want to update the answer now to include a bit about Atom being one of the main characters in the upcoming Legends spinoff.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. We have already seen his superhero armor on Arrow, but the producers said we're not going to see him alter his size soon. So, in this season it is most likely that he is going to be a vigilante on Starling with his armor and the size modification ability is probably going to be seen at the end of the season/season 4.
Hope I helped you